# Import Data fails on multiple CSV files

Tags: postgresql, dbeaver

I have 1000 csv files I want to import into a local PostGres DB.

Each file is the same format and all include a header row. The data per file is however different.

When I attempt to import data using more than one file I get the following error:

[image]

When I import data one file at a time it works.  Any hints please?

Attempted:

- Tried importing one file at a time and it works.
- Used the same db for all files.
- Tried ignoring the file headers.
- Change the db table so every column is text, so it is not column specific
- Change to allow null values

Comment: have you checked that on the file giving error All address1 are filled? Did you alow NULL values for that column? (just in case...)

Comment: How do you execute the COPY statement? That exact query please, and the content for the line where you get the error message. Because there is a mismatch between the two

Comment: 1) `COPY` only works with one file at a time, so how are importing 1000 files at a time? 2) *Missing data for column ...* generally means you have more headers then data in a row. That can happen with a trailing `,` on a row as that implies another data value should be present.